# Set of points $M(z)$

Tags: complex-numbers, complex-geometry

Suppose $z \in \mathbb{C}$ and $a=-1+i$ and $\forall z \in \mathbb{C}\setminus{a}$                        $\quad f_a(z)=\dfrac{az}{z-a} $ we suppose in a plan $(P)$:

$(D)=\{{M(z) \in (P), arg(f_{a}(z)-a) \equiv \frac{3\pi}{4}[2\pi]}\}$.

How can I determine $(D)$?

(Or how can I determine the set of points $M(z)$ that fulfill the above relation?)

Comment: What is $M$?  What is a plan?  What is $(P)$?  If $(D)$ is supposed to be a set, your notation for describing sets is wrong (or at least very non-standard).  This question is unreadable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set $w=re^{i\theta}$ with $\theta=3\pi/4$ and $r\geq0$, the condition becomes
$$\frac{az}{z-a}-a=w$$
that is
$$az=az+wz-a^2-aw$$
$$z=\frac{a}{w}(a+w)$$
and we note that $z-a=\frac{a^2}{w}$, therefore $\mathrm{arg}(z-a)=2\mathrm{arg}(a -\theta$ which is constant.
On the other hand, $|a^2/w|=|a|^2/r$ can be any positive real number.

Therefore, $M(z)$ is an open half-line from $-1+i$, inclined with angle $3\pi/2-3\pi/4=3\pi/4.$

This means that $M(z)$ is a fixed line for $f_a$.